# What is different between django foreigin key in string and without string?

Tags: django, django-models

I am not getting why people write foreign key in two way and what is the purpose of this? are they both same or any different?

I notice some people write like:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and some people write it like:

```
author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What is different between these? is there any special purpose of writing like this or they both are same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is different between these? is there any special purpose of writing like this or they both are same?

They both result in the same link yes. The string will later be "resolved", and eventually the `ForeignKey` will point to the `Author` model.

Using strings however is sometimes the only way to make references however, if the models to which you target need to be defined yet. For example in the case of a *cyclic* reference.

Imagine for example that you define relations like:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    favorite_book = models.ForeignKey(Book, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here a `Book` refers to an `Author`, and an `Author` refers to a `Book`. But since the `Book` class is not constructed at the time you construct the `ForeignKey`, this will give a `NameError`.

We can not define the `Author` after we defined the `Book`, since then we refer to the `Author` before it is constructed (and this thus will again yield a `NameError`).

We can however use strings here, th avoid the circular reference, like:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    favorite_book = models.ForeignKey('Book', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

By using a string, it is fine for the Python interpreter, since you do not use an identifier that is not yet defined, and Django will then, when the models are loaded, replace the strings with a reference to the corresponding model.

The [documentation on a **`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> If you need to **create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined**, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself (...)

If the model is defined in another app, then you can refer to it with `app_name.ModelName`.

Comment: Thanks for your time, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Say you have laid your models out like this:

```
models/
    __init__.py
    model_a.py
    model_b.py
```

This is a common layout when you have an app with a lot of models and you want to better organize your code. Now say `ModelA` has a foreign key to `ModelB` and `ModelB` has a foreign key to `ModelA`. You cannot have both files importing the other model because you would have a circular import.

Referencing another model by string allows you to "lazily" reference another model that it has not yet loaded, this solves the problem of having circular imports